# Why isn't some components on JFoenix not working in scene builder?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix, javahelp

I just started learning java gui and I chose to learn javafx. I use intellij for my java program, I have java jdk 20.0.1 and open javafx sdk 20.0.1 also scenebuilder 20.0.0. The Jfoenix jar I downloaded was 9.0.10 jar. When I downloaded Jfoenix and I added it to my scenebuilder and some components like buttons and checkboxes worked but other components like text fields and textarea does not?

I tried downloaded all three types of Jfoenix jars(jfoenix 8 and android) but no of them worked. I think I downloaded the right jar. I tried looking on YouTube but most of the videos are old or when I copy the exact movements it works for them and not for me.

If you know How i can download and use ALL components for JFoenix 9 please help me.

thanks

Comment: Note: [JFoenix](https://github.com/sshahine/JFoenix) seems to be a dead project and has some issues regarding JPMS modules (or at least used to), which may be why you're having problems in _Scene Builder_. Consider [MaterialFX](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX) instead.